# Plugins in Maven and POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I just started using Maven and I read that plugins are additional components that can be used.
A typical structure of `pom.xml` file is

```
<project>
  <groupId>org.koshik.javabrains</groupId>
  <artifactId>JarName</artifactId> (A fldernamed JarName was created) 
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JarName</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Question**: Where should I insert a `plugin` tag? such as the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>bind</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Before the dependency or after the `dependency` tag? Does it matter?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<project>
    <groupId>org.koshik.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarName</artifactId> (A fldernamed JarName was created) 
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>JarName</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bind</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can also place plugins in the `<build>` section of `<profile>` if you use maven profiles. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: I have a multi pom project for api automation testing. One of the maven projects has automation tests. The build section of the project pom had only 1 plugin - maven surefire plugin with reference to a suite. The entire build tag was removed. Could you please tell me what this means ? thanks.

Answer (score 29):

**A late clarification on two important points**

**Where to place `plugin`**
A `plugin` should indeed be added in most of the cases within the `build`/`plugins` section, however there is **an important difference** between placing it within `plugins` against placing it within `pluginManagement`/`plugins`.

This misunderstanding is **often** the cause of a non invoked plugin in Maven or an harder troubleshooting:

- Plugins under `build`/`plugins` are directly part of the default Maven build, if they specify an `execution` or if they configure something for the default build (see below)
- Plugins under `build`/`pluginManagement`/`plugins` are not necessarely part of the default Maven build, that is, is a management, it's an hint to maven: it you happen to use this plugin, then please use the version, the configuration, the executions I specify here, in this management.

  **But what *happen to use* means?** Means: if the same plugin is **also** present in the `build`/`plugins` section, then apply this management (and only then it will be effective); **or** if the plugin is invoked by default by Maven, then also apply it.

  **But how is a plugin invoked by default?** That's part of the main philosophy behind maven: convention over configuration. By convention, when you specify a certain `packaging` (default `jar`, but it can be `war` for example), you want certain plugins to be invoked. To build a `jar`, [by default](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) invoke the `maven-jar-plugin`; to build a `war`, [by default](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging) invoke the `maven-war-plugin` and so on. So, if you specify a plugin configuration in the `build`/`pluginManagement`/`plugin` for a plugin which has a default binding to the Maven build, then it will be also be used.

**Ordering**
Concerning the ordering of sections within the `pom.xml` file, **a further clarification** is required: it's indeed irrelevant in most of the cases, however the order of `plugin` element wihtin the `build`/`plugins` section may be important. Since Maven **3.0.3** ([`MNG-2258`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2258)), different plugin executions attached to the same Maven phase will be invoked in their order of declaration in the `pom.xml` file. That is, **ordering is important** in this case, since it may affect the behavior of the build.

Additionally, also order of `dependency` declarations may affect your build towards [Dependency Mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), that is, the first declared dependency wins in case of conflict against a transitive dependency. So, once again, **ordering is important in certain cases**.

Last but not least, although ordering is not important for other sections of the `pom.xml` file, good habit is to follow official [Maven recommendations](https://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html) and, as a simplified version, follow this order of declaration:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion/>

  <parent/>

  <groupId/>
  <artifactId/>
  <version/>
  <packaging/>

  <properties/>

  <dependencyManagement/>
  <dependencies/>

  <build/>

  <reporting/>

  <profiles/>
</project>
```

The [`sortpom-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/Ekryd/sortpom) can also be used to automatically apply this standard ordering, simply invoking the following on the concerned `pom.xml` file:

```
mvn com.github.ekryd.sortpom:sortpom-maven-plugin:2.5.0:sort \
     -Dsort.keepBlankLines -Dsort.predefinedSortOrder=recommended_2008_06
```

---

**For further reading**:

- [Stack Overflow: Maven: what is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement)
- [Official Maven doc: Maven POM Reference, PluginManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)
- [Official Maven default bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html)
- [Official Maven doc: Dependency Mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- [Official Maven doc: Maven Code Style And Code Conventions](https://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html)

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks!

Comment: *"or if the plugin is in invoked by default by Maven"* thank you; this is what I suspected, but was unable to verify until this post. It is never mentioned as an exception to the rule when discussing `pluginManagement`; it is always said that unless you explicitly invoke a plugin from `pluginManagement`, it will never run. That is generally true, except for default plugin bindings for the package type. Thank you for explaining this so well.

Answer (score 7):

`<plugin>`should be placed into `<plugins>` section which should be placed into `<build>` or `<pluginManagement>` section. 
The order of `<dependency>` or `<build>` section doesn't matter.

The full reference about pom.xml is here: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: I have a multi pom project for api automation testing. One of the maven projects has automation tests. The build section of the project pom had only 1 plugin - maven surefire plugin with reference to a suite. The entire build tag was removed. Could you please tell me what this means ? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the plugin for build you can use the below structure.

```
<project>
 <build>
  <plugins>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Okay. You mean in order to add plugin tag to the file above i just need to add <build> <plugins>..</plugins? </build>  and no need to add the <project> tag since it is already present at the top . Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes you don't need add project again. I just gave the complete structure.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao - I have a multi pom project for api automation testing. One of the maven projects has automation tests. The build section of the project pom had only 1 plugin - maven surefire plugin with reference to a suite. The entire build tag was removed. Could you please tell me what this means ? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert your second snippet anywhere in the pom.xml file between two `<plugins>` `</plugins>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Sections order in POM doesn't matter. In general, there are build plugins and reporting plugins in Maven. Your case is to use build plugin so you have to put this `<plugin>` block into `<project><build><plugins>...` section.

Look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) for some basics about plugins.

Answer (score 1):

As additional answer for Reporting Plugins (e.g. maven-checkstyle-plugin) there are 2 tags under which plugins can go in pom.xml, under build and reporting.

> Using the reporting Tag VS build Tag
>
> Configuring a reporting plugin in the `<reporting>` or `<build>` elements
> in the pom does NOT have the same behavior!
>
> ```
> mvn site
> ```
>
> It uses only the parameters defined in the `<configuration>`
> element of each reporting Plugin specified in the `<reporting>` element,
> i.e. site always ignores the parameters defined in the `<configuration>`
> element of each plugin specified in `<build>`.
>
> ```
> mvn aplugin:areportgoal
> ```
>
> It uses firstly the parameters defined in the `<configuration>` element
> of each reporting Plugin specified in the `<reporting>` element; if a
> parameter is not found, it will look up to a parameter defined in the
> `<configuration>` element of each plugin specified in `<build>`.

Source: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_reporting_Tag_VS_build_Tag