# Docker spring-boot-maven-plugin java jar ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, executable-jar

I tried use `docker-compose`, `docker` build a demo Spring-boot project and run on `docker`. But created the jar file, and that throw `ClassNotFoundException`, when the `CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]` command has triggered from `Dockerfile`.

- I did use `docker-compose run` to build & run.
- I tried many solution from `StackOverflow`, didn't solve the problem.

My `docker-compose` file:

```sh
version: '3.5'
services:
  demo-service:
    container_name: demo-service
    build:
      context: ./demo
      dockerfile: dockerfile.demoservice.mvn
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    # depends_on:
    #   - demo-service-db
```

`Dockerfile` file:

```sh
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build

RUN mkdir /home/app
COPY ./pom.xml /home/app/pom.xml
COPY src /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package spring-boot:repackage
RUN ls /home/app/target

# Package stage
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/demo.jar
EXPOSE 9091
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]
```

There is the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
        <!-- If I remove this, java -jar will be thrown no main manifest attribute (maven) -->
        <start-class>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
...
...
...
    <build>
<!-- Didn't solve the problem: no main manifest attribute-->
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<!-- Didn't solve the problem: no main manifest attribute-->
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                                <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <!-- Didn't solve the problem: no main manifest attribute-->
<mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <!-- Unable to find main class-->
                    <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

The project structure is as initialized, didn't change anything. (main function in `java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java`)

The error message is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.DemoApplication`.

- Java version 11;
- Spring boot version 2.6.3
- maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim
- openjdk:11-jre-slim

Where did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: if you directly run the jar file without docker, does it still work?

Comment: I have installed `Apache Maven 3.6.3`,  first executed `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`, after that, executed `java -jar ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`,  and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to use the plugin. pluginManagement won't really activate the plugin, but it is just to make the plugin available for the maven sub module to use. Basically, pluginManagement is just to declare that this plugin is available for use.

see: [Difference between <plugins> and <pluginManagement> tag in Maven `pom.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736876/difference-between-plugins-and-pluginmanagement-tag-in-maven-pom-xml)

You should still use this plugin below:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

You might be able to remove the executions tag from the plugin above as you have declared it in your pluginManagement. Try it out and see. Try running the standalone jar without the docker first.

Comment: It can be packaged and executed correctly without `Docker`, but when I use `docker-compose` and `docker`, it fails.