# Can't get checksum maven plugin to execute automatically

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am using the [Maven Checksum Plugin](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/), and I am having problems getting it to execute after the war has been built. Here's my configuration in my superpom under the  section:

```
<build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                ...
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-artifact-checksum</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>files</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fileSets>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/artifacts</directory>
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn package`, the plugin isn't executed. Not *there's an error*, but just doesn't execute. Nothing is printed out during the build process. The war is processed, the build is declared *successful*, and the plugin doesn't execute.

I've tried removing the `<phase>` entities and run `mvn verify` because according to the documentation on the plugin, the `checksum:files` goal is automatically bound to the `verify` phase. Still no execution.

However, the plugin does work if I run:

```
$ mvn checksum:files
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: In your superpom, is this code under `pluginManagement` section or just `plugins`?

Comment: Well, `<plugins>` is under `<pluginMangement>` which itself is under `<build>`. The rest of my plugin configurations are also there too, and  they all work. I've updated my question to reflect a bit more of this hierarchy. In some, the `<configuration>` is under the individual `<execution>`, but that doesn't seem to work for this plugin. It has to be outside the `<execution>` entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is not executed because it is declared under the `pluginManagement` section of your `pom`.

You should move the configuration of `checksum-maven-plugin` outside `pluginManagement` like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            ...
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-artifact-checksum</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>files</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/artifacts</directory>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement) for a description of `pluginManagement` section.

Comment: Intersting. I put this inside the `<pluginMagnagement>` section because this was a super pom, and I wanted the projects that use this POM to automatically generate check sums. All the other plugins listed under plugin management were *standard* plugins, so I guess that's why I didn't notice it before. Adding it to a non `<pluginManagement>` section causes `mvn install` to fail because there's no files to take the checksum of. I tried setting `failOnError` to `false`, but it still won't install. Oh well, I guess I'll manually do a `checksum:files`. It's mainly for Jenkins anyway...