# Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update failed

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, maven-3, pom.xml, multi-module

What I am trying to do is to deploy/update my web aplication using he google `appengine` plugin for maven.

Therefore I added the plugins in my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<project>

    <!-- .. -->

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                                <version>${app.version}</version>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <set_default>true</set_default>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I also added the pluginGroup:

```xml
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
    <pluginGroup>com.google.appengine</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
```

However, if I call `mvn appengine:update` I am receiving

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] mz-parent
[INFO] mz-web-shared
[INFO] mz-data-model
[INFO] mz-web-client
[INFO] mz-mobile-rest-shared
[INFO] mz-mobile-rest-api
[INFO] mz-web-server
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mz-parent 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update (default-cli) > package @ mz-parent >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (enforce-maven) @ mz-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update (default-cli) < package @ mz-parent <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update (default-cli) @ mz-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Updating Application
[INFO]
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] mz-parent .................................... FAILURE [  0.390 s]
[INFO] mz-web-shared ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mz-data-model ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mz-web-client ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mz-mobile-rest-shared ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mz-mobile-rest-api ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] mz-web-server ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.460 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-18T00:33:58+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update (default-cli) on project mz-parent: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update failed. NoSuchElementException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update (default-cli) on project mz-parent: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.32:update failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:154)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.find(Iterators.java:717)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.find(Iterables.java:646)
        at com.google.appengine.SdkResolver.getSdk(SdkResolver.java:50)
        at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.resolveAndSetSdkRoot(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:393)
        at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

**Question**: how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the full stack trace of the error help in any way? (running with the `-e` switch).

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan I have updated my question after using the `-e` switch but the output does not really help me here ^^

Comment: Well, actually it narrowed down the error to the `SdkResolver` class at line 50. It seems that the plugin can't find the right appengine version to retrieve from Maven.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan Okay, if you put it that way .. you're right :D Okay that's interesting then the question is actually *why* it doesn't find it actually :/ my pom.xml doesn't look incorrect to me.

Comment: Well, looking at the `pom.xml`, what I have to say is to test whether the profile is really being activated. You can explicitly activate it by adding an `<id>yourProfileId</id>` tag into it and then running `mvn appengine:update -P yourProfileId`.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan Back at this.. ^^ Adding the profile didn't change it. Same error as before :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have a multi-module Maven project and you are trying to execute the `appengine:update` goal on the whole build, which is probably not possible, because the parent/aggregator pom (where the build is failing) would not provide the folders structure the goal is expecting and as such causing errors.

In fact, you don't want to execute `appengine:update` on the parent, the shared or model module, among others.

You should build the whole project via the standard

```
mvn clean install
```

Then only execute the `appengine:update` on the concerned war/ear module (`mz-web-server` in your case, I suppose), that is, the module which you effectively want to update to GAE.

```
cd mz-web-server <-- move to the concerned module
mvn appengine:update
```

---

If the profile you mentioned is defined in the aggregator/parent pom and activated during the multimodule build, then running `appengine:update` from the root directory will use the defined configuration and try to perform the `update` goal on each and every module, which is something you don't want (and you actually cannot, given the error, reasonably).

If you want to keep on running `appengine:update` from the root and only execute it on the concerned module, then you should edit your `pluginManagement` configuration above:

- Keep on `pluginManagement` only the plugin declaration (groupId, artifactId, version)
- Move the configuration of that plugin on the concerned module (the `mz-web-server` module)
- Remove the `appengin-maven-plugin` declaration from the `plugins` section of the root pom and move it to the concerned module (with the configuration moved above, actually).

As such, the plugin will be declared as managed by the multi-module build (via `pluginManagement`) but not effectively used in each and every module (via `plugins`), then only declared and used in the concerned module.

Moreover, since you are not defining any `execution` of the plugin during the default build, you don't even need a profile I believe. The configuration you defined will only be used by explicit command line invocations, nothing else.

---

Basically, you could have in your aggregator/parent pom the following:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- do you really need it? :) -->
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Then, in your `mz-web-server` module the following:

```
<project>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- you don't need to re-define the version here -->
                <!-- version is taken from pluginManagement from the parent -->
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <version>${app.version}</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- again, no version here -->
                <configuration>
                    <set_default>true</set_default>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note the different usage of `pluginManagement` and `plugins` within the `build` section. For further reading, check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement).

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for this elaborate answer! This works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of working pom.xml from one of my GAE projects :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.gae.mvn.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gae-maven-demo</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <app.id>your-app-id</app.id>
        <app.version>1</app.version>
        <appengine.version>1.9.32</appengine.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.74.v20150814</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>

                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <version>${app.version}</version>
                </configuration>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <set_default>true</set_default>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Hope this helps!