# Why is my target not getting executed?

Tags: maven, m2e, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to get ready for deployment and therefore I want to copy the correct configuration files to `WEB-INF/classes/` *before* everything gets packed into the WAR file for either *deployment* or *development*.

In the end I want to execute deployment-tasks whenever I call

```
mvn glcoud:deploy
```

- which is when I need deployment configuration files - and development-tasks whenever something else gets executed in my project directory.

At the moment I have not decided how exactly I'm going to do it but first of all I try to execute such a "dummy task". Unfortunately it is not working.

This is the profile I configured in the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<profile>       
    <id>default-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement> 
            <plugins>                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>                          
                    <executions>                        
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <echo message="Hello World!"/>
                                    <copy file="src/main/resource/x.xml" todir="src/main" />
                                </target>
                            </configuration>                                    
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>                           
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement> 
    </build>
</profile>
```

It is supposed to `echo` "Hello World!" and copy a **x.xml** file from A to B. I decided to do this in the `compile` phase which means

```
mvn clean compile
```

should actually be enough to get the `target` executed but .. I wouldn't be here if it worked.

**Question**: Does somebody know why this is not getting executed?

---

As mentioned in a comment, I could/should remove `pluginManagement` from `build`. However, this would give me an error saying:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (execution: compile, phase: compile)
```

I've added `pluginManagement` according to an answer of the question "[How to solve “*Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration*” for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)".

---

The solution below is giving the same “*Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration*” error

```
<profile>       
    <id>default-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>   
    <build>
        <pluginManagement> 
            <plugins>                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>                          
                    <!-- -->
                    </executions>               
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>         
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    

</profile>
```

and I am seeing the same for:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>       
        <id>default-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>       
        <build>
            <pluginManagement> 
                <plugins>                   
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>                          
                        <!-- -->                
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>    
    </profile>      
<profiles>
```

Comment: remove the `<pluginManagement>` element, that is, put it into `build/plugins` and not into `build/pluginManagement` section.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo I had to add it because otherwise m2e identifies an error as described in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin).

Comment: argh, it's too long to describe in a comment, I need to write an answer then.. ok

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Looking forward to it :D

Comment: Apart from the above you should never copy (it does not matter how) into `src/` cause it's under version control. Furthermore what you are doing is copying from `src/main/resources/` which is by default handled by the resources copying...so no need to add `maven-antrun-plugin`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make m2e happy and yet being able to meet your requirements, try the following:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement> 
        <plugins>                   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>                          
                <executions>                        
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Hello World!"/>
                                <copy file="src/main/resource/x.xml" todir="src/main" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>                                    
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>                           
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the additional `plugins` section which is basically just repeating the `artifactId` of the plugin.

What's happening here:

- Via the `pluginManagement` section we are telling Maven: whenever the build (via POM configuration or command line execution) needs to execute this plugin, then apply this version by default and this configuration an executions
- The m2e not-so-perfect integration between Maven and Eclipse will then be happy about this plugin configuration, however no plugin execution will ever happen unless we effectively declare it
- Via the `plugins` section we are eventually really defining our build, telling Maven to add this plugin to its build plan. No need to specify version, configuration or executions, since we already defined them into the `pluginManagement` (that is, management of plugins), which will be applied as default configuration/behavior.

For further details concerning the difference between plugins and pluginManagement, check the [reference post on SO: Maven: what is pluginManagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement).

---

Further note on the associated `phase` for such an execution: the `prepare-package` phase would be a more (semantically correct and maintenability-friendly) choice than `compile`. Check the [official Build Lifecycle phases list](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) for more details. Concerning `prepare-package`:

> perform any operations necessary to prepare a package before the actual packaging.

---

**Update**
It appears that not only as described above the `prepare-package` phase would be a better choice, but it also the right phase to make the m2e plugin perfectly happy in this case.

Comment: Nit-pick but I would have `<phase>prepare-package</phase>` since apparently this should be invoked to set-up the correct config in the packaging.

Comment: @Tunaki definitely good point, my focus was on the build configuration, but this is definitely worth to add and clarify, I'll update accordingly!

Comment: If I do it *exactly* like you did it like placing it *right below* `pluginManagement` then I get that "*Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration*" error ..

Comment: @displayname what is not working? I just tried your code and got HelloWorld! in the console. Concerning Eclipse, the phase is the issue in its default mappings, chaging it to prepare-package solved the issue. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo That was the problem! Using `prepare-package` does work for me as well. Sorry, I didn't see that you updated your answer already!

Comment: @displayname no problem, but good I also gave it a try hands-on, always better ;-)

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Thanks for helping me! :)

Answer (score 1):

See [POM Reference, Plugin Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management):

> - **pluginManagement**
>
>   However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children.

That means declaring a plugin in `<pluginManagement>` is just half of the story. You have to declare it in a `<build>/<plugins>` section, too, to actually execute its goal.

In your case:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the proposed solutions but it's still the same :/

Comment: Appears that your answer is correct so far but another problem was the phase `compile` +1 anyway.