# How to run tomcat7-maven-plugin in debug mode with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, tomcat7-maven-plugin

My issue is that i can't run remote debug with tomcat7-maven-plugin.
What i use:

- Maven
- Tomcat7 plugin to maven
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2.2

Ofc Maven is provided by default with IntelliJ. I already tried with 
mvnDebug tomcat7:run command but intelliJ doesn't resolve mvnDebug phrase in maven's built-in command line. Can't use cmd command line neither because i can't find 'home' path since maven is built-in intelliJ. Tried  configure remote-debug with intelli also but get confused. 
Also can't find tomcat7 plugin in "Maven Projects" window. But i'm sure it is, since tomcat7:run command starts tomcat container and app works.

Comment: Regarding not being able to see Plugins section, what _do_ you see under your project node in `Maven Projects` ? Can you upload a snapshot of Maven Projects (either embed in your question or if the upload image privilege is not yet available to you then please upload on imgur or some place and post the link here)? Also is it worth comparing your `<plugins>` section with the one in the repository linked in my answer? [*Here*](https://github.com/javacreed/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-with-maven/blob/master/pom.xml#L19) is the pom from that repo.

Comment: A snippet of your `<plugins>` section would also be useful.

Comment: Screens of Maven Settings and Projects tab: http://imgur.com/a/B6Ys6 http://imgur.com/a/9Y554 Here is a snippet from parent pom file  http://pastebin.com/cyCLrCzd

Comment: It's plugins section in each module doesn't have tomcat7. Here is a link to project: https://github.com/PiotrBartoch/Cats

Comment: Perfect! Lemme have a look at the project

Comment: Is is as I suspected (and the reason why I asked for a snippet of the pom). I'll update my answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Intellij IDEA, in the `Maven Projects` tab, dig down to the `tomcat7:run` goal and then right click and select `Debug` like so:

[image]

In the abouve, notice that there is a breakpoint on Line 34 of `HelloServlet.java`. Now as soon as you hit the URL mapped to the servlet (http://localhost:9090/hello in this case), the breakpoint gets hit as seen below:

[image]

The code used to test this is at the following repository: https://github.com/javacreed/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-with-maven

Regarding not being able to see `Plugins` in `Maven Projects` (sorry I missed that you've mentioned this), note that `Plugins` is not a top level node in 'Maven Projects' .. but will be under a node named taken from `<name>` of your project's root pom. Based on my own experience with Intellij 2016.x as well as on the fact that this functionality is pretty basic, I'd be quite surprised if this is a bug in Intellij. I'd suggest that this is either a problem with your pom.xml or a (shudder!) user error.

---

#### Update - `Plugins` not visible in `Maven Projects`

From the pom.xml ([here](https://github.com/PiotrBartoch/Cats/blob/master/pom.xml#L19)), the tomcat7 plugin is in the `build -> pluginManagement -> plugins` section. This section is intended to be used in a root pom (as you have) to centralize the plugin configuration which can then be inherited by any of the child modules by simply mentioning the plugin. But without doing so, the tomcat7 plugin will not be available anywhere. Therefore, you must have a `build -> plugins -> plugin` section with the tomcat7 maven plugin somewhere (Also see relevant question : [Maven: What is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement))

For example the following change ([here](https://github.com/PiotrBartoch/Cats/pull/1) is the corresponding pull request for your repo):

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Added to `<build>` section of your root pom, immediately results in the Plugins section, along with the tomcat7 goals, to appear in `Maven Projects` :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly as I told above, there is no tomcat7 plugin visible in "Maven Projects" tab... Maybe You know how to tunr it on? I added plugin with pom file and it works fine for deploy purposes "tomcat7:run" only...

Comment: Update: I've already done this. in command line set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"  and configured intelliJ run/debug->edit configurations->remote-> host: localhost port:8000. And when i start debugging i got this: "Error running tomcat-7-debug: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: I think the primary problem here is that you can't see `Plugins`. When you `Debug` on the plugin goal from within Intellij you do not need to do anything else (i.e. no need to setup MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS etc).

Comment: I've requested more information to solve the invisible `Plugins` problem.

Comment: Thank's a lot! you rescued me!

Answer (score 14):

you can run tomcat with maven with this command:

`mvn tomcat7:run`

and if you want to debug, set this maven options:

`export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`

if you are in windows, use the set command:

`set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`

then you can debug with Eclipse or Intellij.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but I would like to highlight an other more maven friendly solution that uses the same idea behind the answear of @arganzheng. You can actually add debuging options as part of the tomcat maven plugin configuration. The resulting pom would look like

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <systemProperties>
              <MAVEN_OPTS>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000</MAVEN_OPTS>
         </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Creating a jvm.config file in the .mvn folder of the project and adding -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n 
worked. (Spacing is bad, start with the - sign)

Comment: As soon as this is done and pom is reloaded,  debug option is enabled on the Maven project tab. Worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: lkamal - what is "this" and what do you mean by "done"?