# yuicompressor-maven-plugin not working at mvn install or designated phase

Tags: maven, yui-compressor

Here is the maven `pom.xml` build session

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                        <warSourceExcludes>**/*.js,**/*.css</warSourceExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compress</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <jswarn>false</jswarn>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                        <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

and when run `mvn install` or `mvn pre-package`(which is the designated phase ) there is no yuicompressor-maven-plugin working log.

```
$mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gif-www 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gif-www ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gif-www ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ gif-www ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ximing/work/gifmiao/gif-www/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gif-www ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ gif-www ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ gif-www ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [gif-www] in [/home/ximing/work/gifmiao/gif-www/target/gif-www-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ximing/work/gifmiao/gif-www/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [170 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ximing/work/gifmiao/gif-www/target/gif-www.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
```

but using `mvn yuicompressor:compress` can get the yuicompressor log shows that the plugin is working.

and I also don't know how to package the compressed css and js to the war file (with the same file name cause I don't want to tweak the include code in html template). Have been working on this about a whole day, someone give me a clue?

Comment: This case may have solution but the plugin version 1.5.1 has a bug because it cannot be configured for some simple cases. Say we want to configure webappDirectory and sourceDirectory.

If sourceDirectory is configured different from the default then the plugin executes compression twice once with the configured value and then with the default value which defeats the purpose of sourceDirectory configuration.

I haven't been able to compress from a directory that had to have changes made before compression.

Answer (score -1):

You are only defining, but not executing your plugin by putting the configuration between the  tag.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483284/1110843