# Maven compilation fails with maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a project using maven. The compilation fails without giving any clue of why the compilation is failing. I am using Jdk 1.7 to build the code. The same code is getting built without any errors when building via ant

I am getting the below error

```
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/List.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Class.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/transform/sax/TransformerHandler.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Users\vadagr\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.2\gson-2.8.2.jar(com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/IOException.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Iterable.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/SuppressWarnings.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/annotation/Target.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/annotation/ElementType.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/annotation/Retention.class)]]
[INFO] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.class)]]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.531 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-27T18:00:31+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/272M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project Nextouch: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project Nextouch: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1033)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException"
```

Any suggestion would help

Here is the pom.xml

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.Test.Test</groupId>
            <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>Test</name>
            <repositories>

                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Central Repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>


            </repositories>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
                    <version>1.58</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.gephi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ui-utils</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
                    <version>1.58</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                    <version>1.58</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                    <version>0.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.13</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.13</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3x</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jbosssx</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.3</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.9</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.54</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.9</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                </dependency>

                    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0-v20070604</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.mozilla.javascript</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.debug</groupId>
                    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0-v20070607-1800</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>rhino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7R2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>oro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8</version>
                </dependency>       
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                    <version>3.16</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
                    <version>3.17</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.15</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                    <version>3.14</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>6.2.0.jre7</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.11.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xml-security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.53</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                    <version>9.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                    <version>9.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>9.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.53</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.53</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                    <version>4.4.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.53</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>edtftp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>edtftp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox-debugger</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>3.21.0-GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
                    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ca.juliusdavies</groupId>
                    <artifactId>not-yet-commons-ssl</artifactId>
                    <version>0.3.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ogce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.6</version>
                </dependency>


            </dependencies>

         <build>
            <pluginManagement>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                            </compilerArgs>
                            <maxmem>${java.memory}</maxmem>
                            <fork>${java.fork}</fork>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                            <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com\ui\swing/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
         </build>


        </project>
```

Comment: Can you attach pom? In what environment  you run maven,  cmd line?

Comment: I have attached the pom.xml. I am trying this in windows and yes in command line

Comment: Where do you define JAVA_1_7_HOME?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a plugins section to your pom.xml, and your pom xml looks malformed (no opening plugins element)

See this post for more info: [Maven: What is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement)

Since this is a single module project, you can simply replace pluginManagement with plugins as follows.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <maxmem>${java.memory}</maxmem>
                    <fork>${java.fork}</fork>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com\hartehanks\ntouch\ui\swing/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: This is resolved now. the issue was the JDK 1.7 installation in my system