# Create Executable Jar with Maven (maven-assembly-plugin) Not Working vs. Eclipse Export Function

Tags: java, maven, jms

I am trying to create a runnable jar using maven (maven-assembly-plugin) which includes all required libraries in a generated jar file, maven successfully creates .jar file however when executing it seems some libraries are not being correctly loaded (specifically it is trying to load com.ibm.mq.jms classes it throws a DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0091), however when exported in eclipse as a runnable jar it successfully creates a runnable jar and when executed no exceptions are thrown. 
Just wondering how I can use maven to do the same as the eclipse export runnable jar function without the exception? 
Note: I have also tried a similar approach using maven-shade-plugin with the same exception thrown.

Here is the relevant build information in my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
   <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-executable-jar-with-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <mainClass>com.tapcons.execute.Execute</mainClass>
             </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. As it is, your question is unclear. What maven command do you use ? Could you please share the exception stacktrace ?

Comment: Hi, could you please send full exception stack trace?

Answer (score -1):

seeing other questions related to this you may should remove ur plugin from the pluginmanagement.
see here:
[maven assembly plugin is not working with pluginManagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089364/maven-assembly-plugin-is-not-working-with-pluginmanagement)