# maven-generated uberjar doesn't contain dependency classes

Tags: maven, uberjar

I'm running maven 3.6.0 on ubuntu 18.04.

My application’s pom.xml includes this dependency; the associated "neptus" jar is in my local .m2/repository:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pt.lsts.neptus</groupId>
        <artifactId>neptus</artifactId>
        <version>x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

My application actually does reference classes from the “neptus” jar file, so I want to include those classes in my project’s uberjar. Therefore the pom.xml also includes this, adapted from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
                <includes>
                  <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                  <include>org/junit/**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </filter>
              <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Yet the uberjar generated by 'mvn clean package' doesn’t contain any class files from the neptus artifact, and so my app throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for those missing classes.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The maven-shade-plugin is ignored by default [if that plugin is enclosed within a pluginManagement block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089364/maven-assembly-plugin-is-not-working-with-pluginmanagement), as it is in my case (sorry, not shown in my original post). The shade plugin *does* get executed if I do this:

```
% mvn package shade:shade
```

as described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208526/maven-shade-plugin-is-not-called-automatically-for-goal-package).