# Execute assembly:single goal during package phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Below is the pom.xml. When I Try running it with `mvn package`, the fat jar is not getting built. But `mvn assembly:single` builds the fat jar.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.xyz.main.MainHandler</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise Added.

Comment: Sorry for repeating my question there. It just not allowing to put my entire code with less number of questions.

Comment: Follow the conventions and remove the configuration `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`....

Comment: Didn't help that.

Comment: Ah not I got it you have defined maven-assembly-plugin in the `pluginManagement` tags...remove them...and then it should work ...apart from that keep the conventions...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I'll try figuring out how did that make a difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after removing the `maven-assembly-plugin` from the `pluginManagement` tags, it worked.

Need clarity checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement).