# Why Intellij Idea cannot generate a maven plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin

[image: phenomenon]

In this picture, I set up a plugin tag in pom.xml in order to use the mybatis-generator-maven-plugin but unfortunately there isn't a plugin in maven projects on the right side. I wanna know what's the problem?

Comment: Silly question: have you tried Maven → Reimport yet?

Comment: Yeah I have. Maybe because of geographical position?@MattBall

Comment: Does it help if you remove comments inside "plugin" tag and reimport project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mybatis-generator `<plugin/>`  should be put outside the `<pluginManagement/>`.

Here's the reference question: [Maven: What is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement)