# Apache CXF WSDL2java pom.xml Configuration

Tags: java, apache, maven, cxf, wsdl2java

Basically what i am trying to do is that i will create wsdl folder under resources and i will add my wsdl files in it. Every time when i run mvn clean install command on console, what  i expect from cxf plugin is create java files from wsdl.

But, regarding to apache cxf documentation, i apply what it says but nothing happens when i run mvn generate-sources (i will use mvn clean install to create java files instead of using mvn generate-sources next step, if you have any advice it would be great also).

What is wrong with this code?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.erkan</groupId>
<artifactId>wsClient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>wsClient</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jaxws-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/is.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your plugin in plugins.

Links:

- http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management
- [Maven: What is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement)

Comment: I removed pluginManagement tag from pom.xml but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, `org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin` does not work inside `<pluginManagement>...</pluginManagement>`.

In my previous CXF projects, I usually put it inside `<plugins></plugins>`. I have already tried with your `pom.xml` and noticed that `cxf-codegen-plugin` has been ignored completed, even though it is still seen in the effective POM.

There is another issue with your original `pom.xml`. In the goal `add-source` of `build-helper-maven-plugin`, the `<source>` (to be added as Java code) should be exactly the folder where the code are generated (i.e. the `<sourceRoot>` of `cxf-codegen-plugin`):

```
<sources>
  <source>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</source>
</sources>
```

Here is the full `pom.xml` that works in my test project with similar settings, you can customize to your needs. I have just added the `-verbose` option so that you can see some information when `cxf-codegen-plugin` is working.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.github.htr3n</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-cxf-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>apache-cxf-demo</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <cxf.version>3.2.7</cxf.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/is.wsdl</wsdl>
                  <defaultExcludesNamespace>true</defaultExcludesNamespace>
                  <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                  </extraargs>
                </wsdlOption>
             </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>add-source</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <sources>
                  <source>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

You only need to run `mvn clean compile` as `compile` includes `generate-sources`.

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
docker run -ti -w /test -v $(pwd):/test maven:3-jdk-8 mvn generate-sources
```

and

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.erkan</groupId>
<artifactId>wsClient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>wsClient</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jaxws-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/is.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```