# Maven Integration Testing Command

Tags: maven, selenium, maven-plugin

I created Maven project using Java for automation testing. When i run mvn verify it does not open any browser. What wrong with it? I can easily run testng class from eclipse but i need to run for CI/CD.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Please help. Thanks.

[image: Maven Console Output]

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: can you share maven console output?

Comment: Added the maven console output.

Comment: there could be many reason for not executing the test. Check you have executable permission on CI/CD  for the file testng.xml or the folder of it. also, don't use plugin management plugin. please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml

Comment: The run failed on locally and it has nothing to do with CI/CD now.

Comment: Move the configuration of maven-failsafe-plugin from pluginManagement to outside of pluginManagement..