# Maven Plugin defined in Parent Pom sometimes does not trigger in Child without declaration

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

In my parent POM, I defined a dependency plugin with phase `prepare-package` inside `<pluginManagement><plugins>`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.resources}</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.dependency}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${classpathDir}</outputDirectory>
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            <excludeClassifiers>${dependencyClassifiers}</excludeClassifiers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In my child POM, I didn't specify any dependency plugin. It didn't get executed. I have to put this in `<plugins>` to get it to trigger:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

The Maven goals I'm using are `clean install`.

My question is, why do I have to explicitly specify `maven-dependency-plugin` again in my child POM?

1. Other plugins like `maven-jar-plugin`, `maven-resource-plugin`, `maven-compiler-plugin` are running even though I didn't re-declare them in my POM. Why is it inconsistent?
2. dependency's phase was configured as `prepare-package`, which is before `package` phase in the Maven [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), hence I presume it should have been "executed in the order given up to the point of the one specified". But it isn't, why?

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help with my enquiries! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is pluginManagement in Maven's pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml)

Comment: No it does not answer why some plugins can trigger, while some can't, even though all of them are inside <pluginManagement>

Comment: These plugins are part of the [built-in lifecycle bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

Comment: Thanks, both your comments have together managed to answer my question. If you want you can create an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section `<pluginManagement>` is used to share plugin configurations between this project and child projects. Plugins are only executed if they are defined in `<plugins>`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483284/4365460) for more information.

However, some plugins don't need to be defined in `<plugins>`. This applies to plugins of the [built-in lifecycle binding](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) like `maven-jar-plugin`, `maven-resource-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: thanks for explaining why some plugins do not need to be mentioned in child projects, as well as the link that points out that `groupId` has also to be defined for all the other plugins (`artifactId` is not enough, and it won't complain)