# maven plugin declared in pluginManagement element works for the current pom

Tags: java, spring, maven

If I declared a plugin under `<pluginManagement>` element and I also want to use it in the same POM, my understanding is that I have to declare it under `<plugins>` element just under `<build>` element, according to explanations in https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management and
[What is pluginManagement in Maven's pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml).

But I found I don't need to declare it under `<plugins>` element just under `<build>` element to use that plugin when execute `mvn tomcat7:run` in [spring-security-oauth sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.5.0.RELEASE/samples/oauth2/tonr/pom.xml). The plugin is [tomcat7-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.5.0.RELEASE/samples/oauth2/tonr/pom.xml#L90).

So I'm curious why it works without declaring it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.5.0.RELEASE/samples/oauth2/tonr/pom.xml#L77).

Answer (score 0):

If you call the plugin explicitly on the command line, as you did, you don't need any declaration at all.

For example, you can call `mvn dependency:list` without ever declaring the maven dependency plugin.

The thing you are talking about is *including plugins into the lifecycle*.

So if you want to call `mvn clean verify` and expect the plugin to run in a certain phase, you need to declare it in `<plugins>` (unless, of course, it is one of the standard plugins of the lifecycle like `compile:compile`).