# what are plugins in pom?

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml

I am working on a pom file of a project, that I've not written any line into it and I'm tryin got understand it.
In the pom there are plugins as follows:

```
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
               </plugin>
           <plugins>
       <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
               <plugin>
               </plugin>
        <plugins>
```

So first of all what are plugins? I searched for them and I understood them a bit but I want to see how others define them, what I understood so far that they are used during the build, is that true?

The other question and the important one is, what is the difference between the 2 plugins section I attached? one under plugin management and the other under plugins.

If there is a good reference to understand pom structure please share it.

THanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Plugins are add-on tools that help us perform some specific tasks, for example, `maven-war-plugin` helps to make a deployable war file. More specifically, if we want to make our build and deployment process easier, we can create plugins and add them in our application.

Comment: Thank you, but to be honest, they're still vague to me, maybe I need to see a real example to understand it well

Comment: Differences: This question has already been answered here. You can check this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483432/4566736

Comment: You can see examples of `<dependencyManagement>` too. Search it in github. I think, that will help you to understand `<pluginManagement>` too.

Comment: Check the documentation first: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html