# Plugins not running in maven project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, checkstyle, pmd, spotbugs

In my pom.xml i have these plugins: checkstyle, pmd and spotbugs. None is running during the lifecycle.

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.unimol.monopoli</groupId>
  <artifactId>monopoli</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>monopoli</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>deploy.repo</id>
      <name>Deploy repository</name>
      <url>file://..\deploy\</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>target/classes/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>it.unimol.monopoli.MainGui</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
            <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>validate</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <linkXref>true</linkXref>
          <inputEncoding>utf-8</inputEncoding>
          <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
          <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Bean.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <excludeRoots>
            <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/stubs</excludeRoot>
          </excludeRoots>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>pmd</report>
              <report>cpd</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate-pmd</report>
              <report>aggregate-cpd</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
          <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I'm new with the pom, so i don't know why they are not running, the lifecycle just start and run all the other default plugins.

If someone can please help me...

Fore more information about my code ask me, thanks

-------udpate--------

Now i corrected the pom:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.unimol.monopoli</groupId>
  <artifactId>monopoli</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>monopoli</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>deploy.repo</id>
      <name>Deploy repository</name>
      <url>file://..\deploy\</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>target/classes/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>it.unimol.monopoli.MainGui</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <?m2e execute onConfiguration,onIncremental?>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
          <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <linkXref>true</linkXref>
          <inputEncoding>utf-8</inputEncoding>
          <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
          <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Bean.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <excludeRoots>
            <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/stubs</excludeRoot>
          </excludeRoots>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>pmd</report>
              <report>cpd</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate-pmd</report>
              <report>aggregate-cpd</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.3.0</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

If someone can se if it is really correct, i really appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this needed: `<url>file://..\deploy\</url>`???

Comment: To tell where to put the folder of the deploy, without it i have that error:  "Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<build>` block is missing the `<plugins>` block therefore none of the plugins are executed.

The `<pluginManagement>` block is an additional block which specifies settings from modules that are inherited from your module. But you still need `<plugin>` block in your pom.xml.

Please also refer to this explanation:
[What is pluginManagement in Maven's pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml)

Comment: Thank you very much, i modified my pom and now i think it works properly. I add the corrected pom in the body of my question, so you, or someone else, can se if it is really correct, thanks.