# Spring Boot application build deployed/builds successfully but crashes due to no main manifest attribute in .jar (Maven)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Trying to deploy a spring boot (maven) application to railway, the application builds/deploys successfully but then crashes due to the following error:

no main manifest attribute in .... .jar

using JDK 17, I have  spring-boot-starter-parent in the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.launchcode</groupId>
    <artifactId>liftoff_kcb_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liftoff_kcb_backend</name>
    <description>liftoff kcb project backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>

                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>

                            <!-- additional annotation processor required as of Lombok 1.18.16 -->
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding
                                </artifactId>
                                <version>0.2.0</version>
                            </path>

                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried adding -

```
<executions>
   <execution>
      <goals>
         <goal>repackage</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

but thought since I have - spring-boot-starter-parent I don't need repackage.

any help would be greatly appreciated, aspiring developer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot Maven plugin should be under `plugins` instead of `pluginManagement`. By placing it under `pluginManagement`, you only make it availabale for use in other Maven modules instead of actually using it in the current one.

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugins intended for use in other modules here -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Related: [What is pluginManagement in Maven's pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/what-is-pluginmanagement-in-mavens-pom-xml)